# Cross Domain Resource Sharing GET: 'refused to get unsafe header "etag"' from Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, rest, cors

A simple GET request with no custom headers. The response is returned as expected. The data in the body is accessible, but not the headers.

When I try to access the "etag" header, browsers raise an exception :

> Refused to get unsafe header "etag"

Chrome, Safari and Firefox all behave the same. I didn't test it on IE.

What am I missing here?

Comment: UPDATE: Only the following headers are accessible:
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Content-Language
- Cache-Control
- Content-Type

Comment: If anyone wants to know when was this fixed, I've found the bugs in [webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41210) and [chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87338&can=1&q=Access-Control-Expose-Headers&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Only simple response headers are exposed when using CORS.  Simple response headers are defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-response-header).  `ETag` is not a simple response headers.  If you want to expose non-simple headers, you need to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, like so:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag
```

However, note that I've noticed bugs in Chrome, Safari and Firefox that prevent non-simple headers from being exposed correctly.  This may be fixed by now, I'm not sure.

You shouldn't need to do a preflight request, since preflight is only required for non-GET/POST http methods or non-simple *request* headers (and you are asking about *response* headers).

Comment: I confirm the support for the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header is buggy.

Comment: I would love to know what makes Last-Modified simple and not ETag. Aren't they supposed to support the same purpose which is cache optimization?

Comment: You make a good point.  I don't know the motivation behind it, but here is a thread that mentions it (I haven't read it yet): http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2010AprJun/0038.html

Comment: I ran into this when designing a resumable upload protocol.  'Content-Length' is deemed an 'unsafe' header to get in response to a http "HEAD" request; what a load.  Only the Safari nightlies seem to respect the 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' header.  Yay WWW.

Comment: Thanks. Its working for me. but when iam making a call into a wso2 api manager url, the same error repeat. Can you help me

Comment: @Mohamed, "buggy"... meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier is this "buggy" for you in chrome it is for me... :S

Comment: I was getting the `refused to get unsafe header "content-disposition"` error message and adding 'content-disposition'  to `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` on the API response solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried AJAX 2.0 (Cross domain sharing) is a methodology fairly recently brought out by W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#ref-cors

Also there is another way of doing this, which is called JSON-P, it's like a JSON request, but you can use it for cross-domains: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Both can be very dangerous to the site owners if not setup correctly though. So do be careful when using it.

[PS]
Not sure if this will help : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Did you read the title of the question? It is supposed to BE CORS

Comment: Oops, I didn't really notice it if I'm honest. But still could use JSONP

Comment: Sure, but it is interesting to know what is going on. Especially since JSONP sucks when it comes to error handling

Comment: yeah I can't disagree with you there. However, I'm not the greatest with CORS as I haven't worked with it too much. I thought I would float some reading material and some ideas their way though.