# How to get Response Header location from jQuery Get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

So I am trying to get the location from a header response via jQuery get. I tried using getResponseHeader('Location') and getAllResponseHeaders() but they both seem to return null.

Here's my current code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var geturl;
   geturl = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://searchlight.cluen.com/E5/Login.aspx?URLKey=uzr7ncj8)',
   });
   var locationResponse = geturl.getResponseHeader('Location');
   console.log(locationResponse);
});
```

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery and AJAX response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header)

Comment: And duplicate of [How to get the final URL after an Ajax redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993442/how-to-get-the-final-url-after-an-ajax-redirect)

Answer (score 34):

The headers will be available when the *asynchronous* request returns, so you will need to read them in the [success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://searchlight.cluen.com/E5/Login.aspx?URLKey=uzr7ncj8)',
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
    }
});
```

Comment: tried that with no luck. The url is not returning a success statement. I tried printing it out on false as well with no luck

Comment: try a `complete: function(xhr){ console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); }`

Comment: The error you get there is probably because of the Same-Origin-Policy.

Comment: @raeq this helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822985/cross-domain-resource-sharing-get-refused-to-get-unsafe-header-etag-from-re

Comment: success method calls only if response status is 200, but in this case I think it is 302

Comment: I don't know if it's changed in the last 7 years, but this no longer works and I don't think it ever should have. Ajax follows redirects, so you would not have a "Location" header because that would create a redirect that would be followed, and you would be returned the resulting page instead. For info see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238727/how-to-prevent-ajax-requests-to-follow-redirects-using-jquery

Comment: @RadleySustaire IIRC only 3xx statuses are followed, OP might get the location header in a 200 response. But I guess when writing the answer, I didn't even look at that part, and only solved the asynchrony issue that the OP had.

Answer (score 8):

for some headers in jQuery Ajax you need to access XMLHttpRequest object

```
var xhr;
var _orgAjax = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
  xhr = _orgAjax();
  return xhr;
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://example.com/redirect',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(xhr.responseURL);
    }
});
```

or using plain javascript

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://example.com/redirect", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseURL);
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: This is not a cross-browser compatible solution.  IE does not support the responseURL property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) and as a result will always be undefined in IE.

Comment: @SunshinyDoyle It's important to tell that this itself is _impossible in IE_. You made it sound like there might be another way, but there is none. This is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery abstracts the XMLHttpRequest object in a so-called "super set" that does not expose the responseURL field. It's in their docs where they talk about the "jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object"

```
For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will expose the following properties and methods:

readyState
responseXML and/or responseText when the underlying request responded with xml and/or text, respectively
status
statusText
abort( [ statusText ] )
getAllResponseHeaders() as a string
getResponseHeader( name )
overrideMimeType( mimeType )
setRequestHeader( name, value ) which departs from the standard by replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating the new value to the old one
statusCode( callbacksByStatusCode )
No onreadystatechange mechanism is provided, however, since done, fail, always, and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements.
```

As you can see there is no way to get hold of the response URL because the jqXHR API does not expose it

Comment: Seemingly the only answer on the page which holds any form of correctness, jQuery doesn't expose responseUrl nor does it provide Location within the response headers.