# Get actual image url after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi Unsplash allows to load random image from their website via:

```
https://source.unsplash.com/random/2560x1440
```

if I access the url from the browser each time the url generates random static image eg:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488616268114-d949a6d72edf?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=2560&h=1440&fit=crop&s=a7f66c8417bcf79d2503b84db64c7b1a
```

I would like to request the image in jquery or js via the first url and in response get the second one. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm having similar problem with laravel. Please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167996/how-to-download-file-from-url-that-redirects-in-laravel/59168262?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the responseURL of the XMLHttpRequest.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL)

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41929637/2442794) for an example in jQuery and native JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PerformanceObserver` to get the `name` property value of the requested resource

```js
const key = "unsplash";

const url = `https://source.${key}.com/random/2560x1440`;

let bloburl = void 0;

let img = new Image;

const getResourceName = () => {

  let resource = "";

  const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list, obj) => {
    // alternatively iterate all entries, check `"name"`
    // property value for `key`, break loop if specific resource requested
    for (let entry of list.getEntries()) {
      let {name: res} = entry.toJSON();
      resource = res;
    }
  });

  observer.observe({
    entryTypes: ["resource"]
  });

  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      observer.disconnect();
      bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      img.src = bloburl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      return resource
    })
    
}

getResourceName().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

You can alternatively use [`Response.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url)

```js
const key = "unsplash";

const url = `https://source.${key}.com/random/2560x1440`;

let bloburl = void 0;

let img = new Image;

const getResourceName = fetch(url)
    .then(response => Promise.all([response.url, response.blob()]))
    .then(([resource, blob]) => {
      bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      img.src = bloburl;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      return resource
    });
    
getResourceName.then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky since there are several things going on.

If you use Chrome or Firefox, open the developer tools and review the network tab you will see that the original request returns an HTTP 302 redirect to a different URL:

[image: network tab in chrome]

The browser then follows the specified `Location` header and you get the page that you see. The image is within an `<img>` on that page.

So to get the final image you need to:

1. Do an ajax request to the initial URL
2. Parse the response headers to get the new location
3. Do an ajax request to the new location
4. Parse the HTML in the new response to grab the actual image URL out of the `img` tag.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://source.unsplash.com/random').then(res=>{console.log(res)})
```

from [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/93r0la/need_help_handling_the_response_from_unsplash_api/) worked for me.