# How to download file from url that redirects in Laravel?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm having a problem with downloading an inline image from summernote
when the image is copied from GMAIL.

The Gmail returns link like this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&ik=d3d2b70b46&attid=0.2&permmsgid=msg-f:1651797278805284123&th=16ec5cdf9c25551b&view=fimg&sz=s0-l75-ft&attbid=ANGjdJ9_MfHq-YioubDagNZ5h216toG9gPg11wV4SkG0Q73urVHcSFnjGKdM4b6b7BfEir0xUp3f4A2ULo9A2srvLz4hlMdP727bJYHpSyL92kesSl3W74lRZFs9HBU&disp=emb&rv71
```

Which redirects to dynamic URL like this:

```
https://gm1.ggpht.com/puicw0cCLZ4huu-Pwk3VHJ8R-wdB2bIHYi4v4F8yUxSnt0UpQQ5LArR9szM5JIqNHPo7JBUbFIf0nsh4JKakewl91Zl08pnNcxmMah6tAFNFWOFaiVJDhxA4RGHvyFxP90HR2DLKHL1MAz8TC9zY8qEliO3vxCv-KqNfq0WBvkFY2fb2GvAWtSTNhksmSHV8_pAKVRyT5aGnbmlH1SWRk_HmTfH27aoslF1P_Lc0245h2nwuhBQ6WpoMgE8eij_Z0QWrHqJWHB0xhAIFAdtIb5E
```

I failed using this `file_get_contents($link)` because I can't get the original link of the image

How can I get the original link of the image in the Laravel Controller?

**Note:** *These are just dummy URLs.*

My question is similar to this: [How to download file from url that redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510762/how-to-download-file-from-url-that-redirects) But I can't seem to find a Laravel version of that.

Comment: both of your url are not working bro

Comment: Hi thankyou for your comment. Sorry, it's a dummy url.
The second url returns the exact image link but it keeps on changing when the first link is clicked.

My question is similar to this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510762/how-to-download-file-from-url-that-redirects

But I can't seem to find a Laravel version of that.

Answer (score 1):

We need to enable redirection.

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'follow_location' => 1,
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/', false, $context);
```

By default, according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) docs, redirection is enabled, however I explicitly enabled it above for educational purposes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, but it still returning the first url not the original url ( 2nd url).

Comment: @Mael What is the http response code of the first url?

Comment: Hi here's the screenshot of what I'm doing. You can view it here.
https://ibb.co/ZgF9CNQ

1st image is I copy the inline image from GMail.
2nd image is I paste it inside a summernote.
3rd image is the link in summernote which was given by GMail when I pasted it.
4th image is when I display the file_get_contents($link) it returns an html not the actual image.
5th image is the url of the image redirection after I pasted the link given by GMAIL.

Comment: The first link that was copied to summernote doesn't provide the real url of the image.
The 2nd link was the original url of the image that I need to copy but I can't get it since I have to open it.

Comment: @Mael Can you copy and paste the 4th image (file_get_contents response) into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)? And post here. The reason this isn't working is because there seems to be some kind of redirection on the page, not an HTTP code redirection (3xx).

Comment: I posted the file_get_contents response of the image

Comment: @Mael  please delete that answer and use a gist (link above). Also please send the html.

Comment: sorry for not being familiar with all of this. 

Here's the link of what I've created.
https://gist.github.com/Mael860/cb72556f01e7de5cd9d737992f5af851

Comment: @Mael  wrong url. Please send the first link (mail.google.com...

Comment: posted it 
https://gist.github.com/Mael860/cb72556f01e7de5cd9d737992f5af851
Thank you so much.