# Google Storage resumable upload range header

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-storage

I'm uploading files to a GCS bucket with the JSON API and the upload is [resumable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable). I'm doing this from the browser using JS.

The files upload with no problems. If there is a network problem then I try to resume it. Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resume-upload) I'm sending an empty PUT request to the upload URI. Then parsing the `range` header of the response. But then I get the error:

```
Refused to get unsafe header "range"
```

This is the code:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PUT", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-range", "bytes */" + file_object.size);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) {
        return;
    }

    if (xhr.status === 308) {
        var range = xhr.getResponseHeader("range");  // Error here
        // continue with the upload
    }
};

xhr.send();
```

I'm creating the upload URI at the server side with Python. These are the headers included in the request:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": authorization,
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "origin": 'http://' + self.request.headers.get('HOST'),
    "X-Upload-Content-Type": content_type,
    "X-Upload-Content-Length": content_length,
}
```

How can I read the header `range`?

Comment: Is this a cross-origin request?  This may be relevant as range is not a simple response header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822985/cross-domain-resource-sharing-get-refused-to-get-unsafe-header-etag-from-re