# How to get Header Location value from a Fetch request in browser

Tags: http-headers, fetch-api

From a ReactJS - Redux front app, I try to get the Location Header value of an REST API response.

When I Curl this :

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN" https://url.company.com/api/v1.0/tasks/
```

I Have this answer :

```
HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 15:55:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://url.company.com/api/v1.0/tasks/status/idstatus
```

When I make a Fetch in ReactJS

```
    var url = 'https://url.company.com/api/v1.0/tasks/'
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            credentials: 'omit',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            }
     )
```

I don't have any Headers in the response object : 
[No header in Fetch request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQyG5.png)

I tried all the response.headers functions I've found in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers :

```
response.headers.get('Location');
```

But well, as headers is empty, I have empty results.

Do you know why I can't get a proper Header object filled with the headers values ?

Comment: It's possible that the fetch api may only expose certain headers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5837798/1515758

Comment: Thx @John, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks to John, I've found the answer.

I just had to put

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
```

To my response headers and it worked, so now I can access Location value with :

```
response.headers.get('Location');
```

Thx John !

Comment: `<ExposeHeader>` for those setting this up in an AWS S3 Bucket Policy CORS XML file

Comment: Basically via CORS, your server code is telling the web browser (running fetch in JS) that it is OK to read the Location: header

Comment: where to write that first line?

Comment: @Prime into the headers of the response you're trying to access there.

Comment: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` on headers didn't work for me

Answer (score -2):

Besides to expose the Location Header in the server.

I just could access the location in the react application with:

```
response.headers.location;
```