# Can't accses fetch() response location header in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, cors, bluesnap

I'm having a problem that already disccussed here at stackoverflow and at other platforms ([1](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/770),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927335/how-to-get-header-location-value-from-a-fetch-request-in-browser)), but the solution that was offered is not possible in my case.

I'm trying to get a Token from BlueSnap (payment proccesing company, [details about the exact action can be found here](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Tools/docs/create-hosted-payment-fields-token)) via POST request and fetch(). the request is working, and the Token is being sended to me via the Location header in the response. **I can see the header and the desired token via Chrome dev tools, but I can't get and use it on my JS code. The response.headers object is empty, and any way I tried to accses response.header.Location failed.**

I tried This:

```
console.log(response.headers.get('location'))
```

And also this

```
for(const header of response.headers){
  console.log(header);
}
```

but none of this seems to work.

[As disscused here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927335/how-to-get-header-location-value-from-a-fetch-request-in-browser) I tried to add this:

```
'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'location'
```

to my list of headers in the request so it fits [CORS policy requiremnts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers), but it didn't help. I think this should be inserted in the server side, and not in the client. My guess is that I`m not the first to enconuter this issue, but the customer suppurt of BlueSnap doesn't have a solution for this. Is the only possible solution is to add the *'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'location'* on there servers?

**My question is this: How can i accses this http response Location header, which is defenatly sent to my browser, but can't be used at the moment with my JS code.**

Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

*I dont think i matter for this specific issue, but I'm working on this project with ReactJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The APIs for making HTTP requests from JavaScript in a web browser (`fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`) follow redirects **transparently**.

The `response` object will contain the response for the request to the location specified in the `location` header. You *never* get access to the response containing the redirect instruction.

---

If you read the [documentation](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Tools/docs/hosted-payment-fields#section-implementing-hosted-payment-fields-in-your-checkout-form) for the API, it says:

> You create a Hosted Payment Fields token for the specific checkout session, using a server-to-server API call.

… so you shouldn't be accessing that from client-side JS in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have read the documentation but didn't understand the meaing of this sentence. I guess this is the solutaion, I'll try and update here if the problem is solved.

Comment: You make the HTTP request using code running on your server instead of code running on the user's browser.

Comment: `fetch()` can be configured to not follow redirects, but unfortunately even then the Location header is not exposed, even when explicitly allowed by CORS headers