# Refused to get unsafe header "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I'm using `amp-iframe` in a page with a Google map in the iframe. The page works fine and validates on all the browsers I tried, except Safari on MacOS.

I get this error in the console:

```
Refused to get unsafe header "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"
```

I tried adding these headers to my server:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
Header set AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin https://example.com
```

However, I still see the same error. It only occurs in Safari. It seems CORS related. Anyone can help?

Comment: Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837798/5832311), only [simple response headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-response-header) are exposed when using CORS. There is also a [reported bug](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/407) in Safari 10. However, it was stated that it should not affect the runtime of your application. It's just a [log](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/7911bb7827474999b46aec95606b6a246bb5d745/src/HTMLImports/xhr.js#L35-L44) by `console.error`.

Comment: If you're still having this issue, can you post a link to a sample page with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue embedding a Google Calendar, it resolved when I added both `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` to the `sandbox` attribute. This sample comes from the [`<amp-iframe>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe) doc:

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
    layout="responsive"
    frameborder="0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDG9YXIhKBhqclZizcSzJ0ROiE0qgVfwzI&q=iceland">
</amp-iframe>
```

If this does not address your issue, could you edit your question to include your `<amp-iframe>` code so we can help?