# How to mimic curl in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, curl, xmlhttprequest

I have one curl command which is responding ok. But same thing when I am trying in java script, it is not giving success.

Curl command that I am running in dos:

```
curl "http://serverip/live/test01/test01_mcs.isml/playlist_high.mpd" -H "Host:actualServer.net" -i
```

This returns a play url.

Same thing I am trying to mimic in JavaScript as

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://serverip/live/test01/test01_mcs.isml/playlist_high.mpd", true);  
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Host", "actualServer.net");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhttp.send();
```

This gives error as "Refused to set unsafe header Host"

I tried `http get` also, but same response.

I tried in Java's AsynHttpClient using `asyncHttpClient.post(url,new ResponseHandler());`.

I tried Java's AsynHttpCLient using `asyncHttpClient.post(mContext, url, entity, contentType, new ResponseHandler())` also. In this I tried passing my host in entity, but no luck.

I am out of options now. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript - which are you looking for? Or do you just need it to work in either?

Comment: either is ok for me. I started with Java then shifted in JavaScript. But as you asked Java's solution is more preferable. Thanks

Comment: Browsers set the Host header — after running your frontend JavaScript code — with the value set to actual host. The actual request headers that the browser sends out in the end are not accessible from your frontend JavaScript code. So even if the browser allowed you to set the Host header from and XHR request, the browser would just end up overwriting the value with the real host value. (Incidentally, for frontend JavaScript code running in a browser, I’d wonder why you’d ever want to (try to) set the Host value from your frontend code anyway…)

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822985/cross-domain-resource-sharing-get-refused-to-get-unsafe-header-etag-from-re)