# Issue with caching and unsafe Etag? Storyline / xAPIWrapper / LMS related

Tags: javascript, http, articulate-storyline, xapi

I'm having an issue with an xAPI package (published from Articulate Storyline). I added a custom JavaScript file that contains the minified xAPI wrapper as well as some custom JavaScript functions to send xAPI statements. This functionality works as desired...the statements send without issue.

I can publish the course to the LMS and access it as desired, but if I exit the course and try returning to it in the LMS, I am faced with a white screen and cannot do anything (whereas normally I'd have the option to Restart or Resume the course).

When the course is set to restart upon revisiting (or when I do not include the minified xAPI-wrapper.js code), this issue does not occur. It's also important to note that the issue does NOT occur in Internet Explorer (but it does occur in Chrome and Firefox)

The console presents these errors:
`app.min.js:3 Refused to get unsafe header "ETag"`
`n @ app.min.js:3`
`app.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`
    `at Object.getSHA1String (app.min.js:3)`
    `at Object.n [as callback] (app.min.js:3)`
    `at TinCan.LRS.requestComplete (app.min.js:3)`
    `at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (app.min.js:3)`

Any ideas what could be wrong here or how I may be able to fix it? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a nosey at this question, it might help point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822985/cross-domain-resource-sharing-get-refused-to-get-unsafe-header-etag-from-re It's likely you are using multiple domains and need to set CORS headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS