# Is there a way to load an html and a JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I want to do is get a JSON object and an HTML view from a single AJAX call.

My current implementation is the JSON object is hidden in some part of the html and just parsed client side.

Is this good practice? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could encode the JSON object into a data attribute on an HTML element

Comment: Can you store the view as a string in a key of the json object? That would be easier than having to parse the json out of the html view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a JSON object with the HTML *inside*:

```
{ "a": "data", "b" : "data", "view" : "<html>...</html>" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (as the option to alter the content type of the original request seems obvious to everyone here) would be to send a custom JSON header.

```
XXX-JSON-Payload: {a:1, b:2}
```

And read that header from JS (*see [getResponseHeader is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444489/getresponseheader-is-not-a-function) for a jQuery method of doing that*).

Answer (score 0):

I would return JSON from the AJAX call, and in one of the JSON attributes, store the encoded HTML.  Seems quite a bit simpler and stable than trying to parse JSON back out of an HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by embedding your JSON into an HTML elements data attribute:

Assuming your ajax call returns this:

```
<json data-obj='{"my":"json","data":7}'/>
<div>My View</div>
```

Then the following will load the view, and extract the data from the attribute

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    $('#content').load('ajax.php', function(data) {
        $(data).siblings('json').remove().data('obj');
    });
</script>
```

(tested with jQuery v1.7.1)